# Hacer scroll a las filas del tbody de una tabla

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-3

Cómo puedo hacer scroll a las filas de una tabla?? los resultados no están paginados y de esa manera creo se puede evitar cuando el número de registros crezca, se mantenga en la vista visible el encabezdo de la tabla y los elementos por encima de ésta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en resumen, hacerle scroll solo a la región sombreada de la imagen.
Este es el código de la vista:

```
{% block vistas %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li>LISTADO DE EMPAQUE&nbsp;-&nbsp;BULTO&nbsp;{{ bulto.numero}}&nbsp;{{bulto.descripcion}}</li>
                <li><a id="lnkRecargaRegistros" href="{{ path('bulto_recargarTablaArticulos', {'bultoId':bulto.internalId|uuid_encode}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>            
    </div>    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a id="lnkNuevoRegistro" class="btn btn-link" href="{{ path('bulto_agregarArticulo', {'bultoId':bulto.internalId|uuid_encode}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;Agregar</a>
            <a id="lnkEditaRegistro" class="btn btn-link disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;Editar</a>
            <a id="lnkEliminaRegistro" class="btn btn-link disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a>
            <a class="btn btn-link lnkClasificarArticulo disabled" href="{{ path('bulto_clasificarArticulos')}}" data-clasificacion="menaje" data-menaje="{{bulto.colaborador.menaje.internalId|uuid_encode}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp;Clasificar como Menaje</a>
            <a class="btn btn-link lnkClasificarArticulo disabled" href="{{ path('bulto_clasificarArticulos')}}" data-clasificacion="enaje" data-menaje="{{bulto.colaborador.menaje.internalId|uuid_encode}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp;Clasificar como Enaje</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <table id="tablaDatos" data-src-eliminar="{{ path('bulto_eliminarArticulo') }}" class="table table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-primary">
                        <th><input class="checkbox"  id="chkTodosArticulos" type="checkbox" title="Marcar todos"></th>
                        <th class="text-center">No</th>
                        <th class="text-justify">Art&iacute;culo</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Es menaje</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Piezas</th>
                        <th class="text-center">USD Totales</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Valor por Piezas (USD)</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Valor Total (Bs.S)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for articulo in articulos %}
<tr>
    <td><input class="checkbox checkbox-articulos" type="checkbox" name="chkArticuloId[]" data-id="{{ articulo.internalId|uuid_encode }}" data-src-editar="{{path('bulto_editarArticulo', {'id':articulo.internalId|uuid_encode})}}" data-titulo-ventana="Editar artículo"></td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ articulo.orden }}</td>
    <td class="text-justify">{{ articulo.descripcion }}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><span id="articulo-{{articulo.internalId|uuid_encode}}" {% if articulo.esMenaje == true %}class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" data-msg=""{% else %}class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" data-msg=""{% endif %}></span></td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ articulo.cantidadPiezas }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ articulo.precioTotalUSD|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ articulo.precioUnitario|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ (articulo.precioTotalUSD*menaje.tasaConversion)|number_format(2,'.',',') }}</td>
</tr>
```

{% endfor %}
                    
                
            
        
    {% endblock %}

Answer (score 1):

Aqui esta la respuesta que estás buscando.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css

si te lo puedo resumir basicamente solo es agregarle la propiedad `overflow:auto;` al div de tu tbody.

Comment: bueno la verdad probé con el overflow sobre el tbody e igual me pone el scrollbar en la página, aunque le puse hiden.